# missing javaws.exe from system32 after update to Java 7 Update 9

Tags: java, java-web-start, updates, missing-data, system32

There seems to be a bug when updating Java to Java 7 Update 9 through GUI in Control Panel. I need to mention that it all has been tested on Windows XP 32 bit. That updates removes javaws.exe (Java Web Start) from C:\Windows\System32. That breaks the shortcuts that point to that location. It can be related to Java Quick Start putting a lock on certain files and the update being unable to copy javaws.exe from its location in Program Files. It does not happen when downloading the offline update file and installing it on top of the current version of Java. The error message that you get when trying to launch our application is

Windows is searching for javaws.exe. To locate the file yourself, click Browse.

Windows will try to locate the file and after some search should find javaws.exe in Program Files and offer to fix the link.
Clicking Fix it resolves the issue by repointing the link to a new location. Other possible solutions for it could be:

1. Uninstalling Java completely and installing the latest version. You get to keep Java cache so you will not have to reinstall your applications.
2. Updating Java by downloading the offline update and installing it on top of the current version of Java.
3. Manually modifying the path of the link.
4. Manually copying javaws.exe to C:\Windows\System32.
5. Reinstalling your application.

Has anyone encountered this problem as well? Does anyone know if there is a fix for it?
Thanks.

Comment: Imo this would better be asked on http://superuser.com

Comment: I had the same issue, I just updated my bookmarks to here instead.    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaws.exe"